# Mirroring on windows 7: missing menu option

Tags: windows-7, mirroring

I'm trying to create a raid 1 configuration (mirroring) on windows 7 with 2 identical HDD.

However, it seems that the option, is not present on my system and I can't understand why.
Is it because I'm using home edition? Is it because of my motherboard? (should I only update my motherboard's drivers or I can't definitely do it?)

Motherboard model: Asrock h67m-ge/ht p1.40

Comment: Hardware Raid is configured during the bios post, that is if the motherboard supports raid, you never stated if you want software or hardware raid.

Comment: I want windows 7 raid 1 (which is software by the way)

Comment: It looks like your motherboard supports hardware raid just fine.

Comment: Yea I solved with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create the raid configuration from windows 7 if it's a home edition. You need a professional one.